# Is JPA annotation mapping a bad approach when separating a model layer as a library?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Suppose you have an N-Tier REST application. Few client applications use this REST service as well (Android, Desktop, etc)

As we know JPA mapping annotations are placed right on model classes for mapping an entity object to the database tables. Now in our scenario, both android and desktop applications also need the model classes for JSON binding and deserialize the JSON data into a correspondent java object.

As we know, a good approach to use the model in all apps is to separate that Model layer into a separate java library and use that in all apps (REST server and the clients)

The question is since we have JPA annotations on java classes in the model layer if we extract that library for the two clients, there are some issues:

- The JPA mapping annotations expose the database design to client apps which is a security issue
- We need to add JPA annotation dependency in those clients which are not practically needed

This leads me to think about JPA xml mapping configs approach for decoupling the JPA mapping configs from the java code classes into a separate xml file and then add the java library as dependency within the three applications (REST server, android, desktop)

Is this the right choice or not and do you know any other approach in this scenario?

Comment: Usually ppl create the shared classes as DTO classes (data transfer object), like PersonDTO.java and JPA annotated classes as PersonEntity.java (or whatever monikers you want to use). Drawback is that you need a beanmapper to convert between them.

Comment: Why is exposing Jpa annotations and database design a security issue?

Comment: @Christine because in client app like android/desktop if the code decompiles they can guess and understand what are the tables and attributes in your database. You can easily decompile java byte codes

Comment: If the model tier decompiles, with a simple hibernate code (hbm2ddl), they could reproduce the whole database!!! and if they know how the design is, they could perform a specific attack against the database!!!

Comment: What you're saying is, you use "security by obscurity".

Comment: @Christine even in obfuscate scenarios, strings are not obfuscated (strings in here means db table & column names)